# Importing content to a content type with images and associated data

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds, tooltips

I'm trying to import images with ALT text and tooltip text into Drupal for a content type.

I'm using Feeds and Feeds Tamper to import the rest of my content right now, like so:
http://learningwithsage.com/wp/?p=212

And here's a technique for importing just the images:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1851322

But I'm still unsure how to do the tooltips and ALT Fields for the images.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal content is store in Databases (SQL) this your text and any link that you inside your content. Images are files that can be call from your content, module or theme.

Tooltips is mainly a front-end work, this is part of the theme or a module. So you do not necessary import from the content from your another framework (or website). You added a module or a theme that support Tooltips.

Here are few modules for Tooltips:

- [qTip](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip)
- [BeautyTips](https://www.drupal.org/project/beautytips)
- [Field Tooltips](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tooltips)
- [Tipsy](https://www.drupal.org/project/tipsy)

You should pick one of these module and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @darol100 I was actually hoping for a way to import the content because the whole reason I'm importing (just once) is so I don't have to go into each individual record and add the icons and other icon-related data.

I'll explore the tooltip solution more though to see if that can help me with this.

Comment: If I'm not wrong as long you have the Alt tag any of this module would automatic created a ToolTips.

Comment: Very good I'll try that. You think I can make a field for the ALT tag right in my CSV import? Well, I'll look in the DB and see how that's stored. Thanks for your help.